# Add records randomly between select result

Tags: mysql

I want to add records randomly in select result like this example:

```
1 a
2 a
- b
3 a
- b
4 a
5 a
6 a
- b
7 a
8 a
- b
```

In a simple query I select from a table but in this case I want result mix with b table without random a result otherwise I simply could union them and then order random().

**EDIT:**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for t1
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t1`;
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('1', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('2', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('3', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('4', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('5', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('6', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('7', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('8', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('9', 'a');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('10', 'a');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for t2
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t2`;
CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('1', 'b');
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('2', 'b');
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('3', 'b');
```

So I can union two tables and then order by random and the result will be like this:

```
SELECT
t1.ID,
t1.name
FROM
t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
t2.ID,
t2.name
FROM
t2
ORDER BY RAND();


5   a
2   a
6   a
3   a
7   a
2   b
9   a
1   a
10  a
3   b
4   a
8   a
1   b
```

But I don't want to random records I just only want mix two tables records like first example.
I hope my question is now clear.

Comment: What is the original table?  What are the "random" rows?

Comment: Please post your database schema (at least table A and B) and improve your question in other ways (the SQL you have tried, explain that "random" thing more).

Comment: So do you want the tables are ordered by ID but joined randomly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think pure SQL is the best solution here, I would do it in some end framework (I don't know what you use), like PHP, Delphi, Java, etc. This way is more easier and you can control it better. But if you would like to do it in SQL, here an idea:

```
SET @max_t1 = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM t1);
SET @max_t2 = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM t2);

SET @last_order = RAND()*@max_t1/@max_t2;

SELECT
    t1.ID, t1.name, t1.ID AS "Ord"
FROM
    t1

UNION ALL
SELECT
    t2.ID, t2.name, @last_order:=@last_order+RAND()*@max_t1/@max_t2
FROM
    t2
ORDER BY Ord
```

This way we generate a random position for TableB, then in every row we add some random value to it, in according to the size differency between the two tables, then order the whole result on this column.

Comment: Interesting way.Thank you.Do you have an idea how can I set a min for distance of table b records?for example min 2 then never two b come together?

Comment: I change second two to this: `t2.ID, t2.name, @last_order:=@last_order+3` and it seems good,What are you think?

Comment: Do you have idea about when we want to repeat b records 5 times?for example we have 3 record in b table but we want they repeat randomly in this query 5 times.Thank you

Comment: To have a min. distance, use this: `@last_order:=@last_order+GREATEST(RAND()*@max_t1/@max_t2*3,3)`

Comment: The repeating is not a good thing is SQL. SQL is not for that type of queries, but if you UNION 5 selects, it should work, but you should use 5 separate last_order values, and it will be slower and slower the more union you use and the more rows you have. I suggest to do it in your application, not in pure SQL.

Comment: What about temp table?So in a procedure  Insert records in table.Has it better performance?

Comment: Absolutely no. When you need temp tables, you are screwed up. I don't know your app, but what  if 10.000 users try to run this query in the same time? And what if the tables had 100.000+ rows? What's wrong with the non-sql based solution?

Comment: Because I cant non-sql based system and I should prepare result.OK you are right but in my case I just run it every minute and only one time,It seems OK,What you think?

Comment: It depends on the size of your DB, the server, and a lot of other things. It can work, but you have to know, it's not the way SQL should be used.